# how to generate .java file from .form file in netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

- In my project (in Netbeans IDE) I have made code changes through design-> Customize code.
- After that I did Clean n build project, so .form file got reflected.
- But I am not able to see reflect changes in .java file even if name of the both .form & .java files is same.
- Am I missing anyy step in between? Is there any other way to do the same?

Answer (score 3):

**What is the .form file?**

The .form file is an XML file that the visual editor uses to store the information about the GUI form. It is much more reliable than reading the information from the source code. You don't need to distribute the .form file with your application; it's only used by the IDE. However, if you want to open your form again in the form editor, you should keep the file.

So you do not want to care about **.form** file. It will automatically get  update when you update the GUI Visually.

To create a new **JFrame** Form use.

**File>New file> JFrame Form>**

To edit it use **.java** file which is visible in the project window. Simply double click the **.java** file and it will bring you the Design Editor.
There is two kind of Views in the editor.

1. **Design View** - You can edit Form using the GUI building tool set.
2. **Source View** - You can alter the java code (define task inside a listeners etc...)
   You can use Design to make GUI changes in the Form and Source to make Code changes.

Do a **Clean Build** or **Build**(I am using Clean build every time because some times IDE get buggy with the Build option) after you done the edit.

That's all.

---

*If .form files visible on your Projects Window , it means a bug, you may update the Netbeans IDE.*
[Bug 202614 - Form Files Sometimes Show in Projects Window](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=202614)